# Structuring XDocument to properly format Tags

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-formatting

I have an `XDocument` being created that gets populated with a set of data.

The output looks like so:

```
    <Results>
      <RuleResult>
        <Title> RuleTitle </Title>
      </RuleResult>
      <RuleResult>
        <Title> Rule2Title </Title>
      </RuleResult>
    </Results>
```

now how I have this formulated in C# is as follows:

```
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Results"));
    foreach (AnalysisSet rules in allAnalysisSets)
     {
       foreach (var rule in rules.Rules)
        {
          doc.Root.Add(new XElement(rule.GetRuleState()));
        }
     }
```

To my understanding, this creates `"Results"` as the root level node.

My question is, if I want to set it up so that encapsulating all of the above is `<AnalysisSets>` so it would be:

```
    <AnalaysisSets>
      <AnalysisSet ProviderName="ProductNameHere">
        <Results>
          <....xml data..../>
        </Results>
      </AnalysisSet>
    </AnalysisSets>
```

How would I do this?  It seems like I would be trying to create a Root element, and then 2 sub root elements?  I am not quite sure how to go about accomplishing that, if that is indeed the right track to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered just using straight up serialization? Anyway here is my complete mockup.

Edit: I forgot the Results node :-)

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var allAnalysisSets = new AnalysisSet[] {
            new AnalysisSet(){
                ProviderName = "productname1",
                Rules = new Rule[]{
                new Rule(){ Title="rule1" }
            } },
            new AnalysisSet(){
                ProviderName = "productname2",
                Rules = new Rule[]{
                new Rule(){ Title="rule1" },
                new Rule(){ Title="rule2" }
            } }
        };

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
        {
            new XElement("AnalaysisSets"
                , allAnalysisSets
                    .Select(set => new XElement("AnalysisSet"
                            , new XAttribute("ProviderName", set.ProviderName)
                            , new XElement("Results"
                                , set.Rules.Select(rule => rule.GetRuleState())
                            )
                        )
                    )
            ).WriteTo(xw);
        }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class AnalysisSet
{
    public IEnumerable<Rule> Rules { get; set; }

    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public XStreamingElement GetRuleState()
    {
        return new XStreamingElement("RuleResult",
            new XElement("Title", Title));
    }
}
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating some `XElement` items before hand and adding them together before inputting the rule xml and then adding the whole thing to the `XDocument`